# Rails server jquery datatables pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, datatables

Because of low performance I change all my `jquery datatables` data to server side (include paging and sorting).

I want to know what the best way to build the query dynamically.

When  the query run?
In this row carts = `Activity.where("sid=33")`

Or just when run `.each carts.each do |key,val|`

This is my code

```
  def cart_activits_service_search
      @site = get_site()
      @site_id = @site.idsite
      @from_date = params['from'] ? Time.zone.local_to_utc(DateTime.strptime(params['from'], "%Y-%m-%d")) : 6.days.ago.beginning_of_day
      @to_date = params['to'] ? Time.zone.local_to_utc(DateTime.strptime(params['to'], "%Y-%m-%d")) : 0.days.ago.to_datetime
      limit = 10
      limit = params[:iDisplayLength] if params[:iDisplayLength].present?
      q = params[:sSearch]
      carts = CartActivity.where("idsite = :site_id and server_time between :from_date and :to_date",:site_id => @site.id,:from_date => @from_date, :to_date => @to_date+1.day)
      @total_count = carts.count
      @sEcho = params[:sEcho]
      #where
      carts =carts.where(" (email like ?) or (traffic_source like ?) or (event like ?) or (recovery_source like ?) ", "%#{params[:sSearch]}%", "%#{params[:sSearch]}%" , "%#{params[:sSearch]}%", "%#{params[:sSearch]}%") if params[:sSearch].present?

      @count = carts.count
      carts = carts.order("email")
      carts = carts.limit(limit).offset(params[:iDisplayStart])

      ret ={}
      ret["sEcho"] = @sEcho
      ret["iTotalRecords"] = @total_count
      ret["iTotalDisplayRecords"] = @count
      ret["aaData"] = []

      carts.each do |key,val|
          @temp =[]
          @temp << key.email
          @temp << key.server_time
          @temp << key.traffic_source
          @temp << key.event
          @temp << key.recovery_source
          @temp << key.cart_total
          @temp << key.cart_items
          ret["aaData"] << @temp
      end

      render :json =>  ret

   end
```

Comment: You can use kaminari for sample - https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

Comment: The best way to build a dynamic query would be to add some form fields that trigger the datatables ajax call on submit.  You have access to your params hash as shown when you assign @sEcho a value so just reach into your params hash and handle accordingly!